# XLib: Get cursor image

Tags: c++, linux, x11, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to retrieve current cursor bitmap using Xlib?
I have checked [XCursor man](http://www.xfree86.org/4.3.0/Xcursor.3.html) but I don't see any method that can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use GetCursorImage / SelectCursorInput + CursorNotify event from [XFixes extension](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/fixesproto/plain/fixesproto.txt):

```
XFixesCursorImage *cursor = XFixesGetCursorImage(display);
```

Comment: Unfortunately for some, `XFixesGetCursorImage` is not directly exposed by python-xlib. I think you see another, very similar approach, [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/e931119a41d0c48d1c544af89768b119b13feb4d/libavdevice/xcbgrab.c#L331-L397).