# How to detect the current mouse cursor type using python in linux?

Tags: python, linux, mouse, mouse-cursor

What I'd like to do is find out the type of cursor (ie. pointer, normal, insert) currently active in Linux using python.

I've found one post mentioning that for windows using `win32gui`: [The way to detect the current mouse cursor type from bash or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097307/the-way-to-detect-the-current-mouse-cursor-type-from-bash-or-python)

`win32gui` is Windows-specific and this library will not work in Linux. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use this library `PyXCursor` to get the image of cursor/mouse-pointer for an arbitrary application window in Linux - in Python using ctypes](http://%20https://github.com/zorvios/PyXCursor/blob/master/pyxcursor/pyxcursor.py)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I have come up with three solutions, but they are rather effort and resource-intensive. And I haven't tested them out, so I don't know about any roadblocks. So at this point, I would still appreciate alternative solutions to this problem.

(1) You could find out the location of the mouse pointer using `pyautogui` and then take a snapshot of the pointer. Then you could compare this image with a test image of a cursor and calculate how similar both images look like using `OpenCV`.

(2) Run win32gui via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) like service and send cursor data to linux application.

(3) Use python's `ctype` module to call [`XFixes` C library's X`FixesGetCursorImage(display)` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942556/xlib-get-cursor-image)

Comment: Could you explain how you do the (3) option?